How to repeat certain labels in enumerate, with apex?
Short story: in the enumerate environment I would like to have something like this:
(a) bla bla
(b) bla bla bla
(b') bla blaa
(c) blbl
(d) blaaa
My current enumerate environment code is this
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item BLA
\item BLAA
\end{enumerate}

Is there something simple I could do? I tried to search over here but I found nothing. Perhaps I've missed it?
Thank you!
P.s. here is the template
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=17mm}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor, cleveref}


How do you want to designate this in your code?  \repeatedItem?  Or pass repeat=2 as an option to enumerate?  Or have an environment repeat around the two items?  It would help a bit if you completed your code with the \documentclass and necessary \usepackage.  For example, are you definitely using the enumerate package, and not the related enumitem package?  And what do you mean by apex in your title?

I added a bit of preamble in the question. By "apex" I mean... the apex! That is after, say, the element (d) I would like the next \item to be (d') (with the apex).

That does not fit any definition of apex that I'm aware of.  I think I'd call that "prime" or "apostrophe".

Just add an optional argument to \item:
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=17mm}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor, cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item BLA
  \item BLAA
  \item[(b$'$)] BLAAA
  \item BLAAAA
  \item BLAAAAA
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}



Here is a fancier version that uses the enumitem package to define a new enumerate environment, called Enumerate, which accepts an \item* for creating these special items.
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\realItem\item
\NewDocumentCommand\FancyItem{s}
{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\realItem[(\alph{Enumeratei}$'$)]}{\realItem}%
}
\newlist{Enumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Enumerate]{before=\let\item\FancyItem, label=\alph*}

\begin{document}
\begin{Enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item BLA
  \item BLAA
  \item* BLAAA
  \item BLAAAA
  \item BLAAAAA
\end{Enumerate}
\end{document}

The output is the same as Stephen's solution. All this does is replace the normal \item command with \FancyItem, which accepts a *-ed optional argument.
It's not ideal, however, in that consecutive \item* will produce the same label. It wouldn't be hard to cater for (b'') etc, with the main problem being that I don't see a good syntax for this. Rather than reinventing the wheel, it is probably better to stick with Stephen's solution so that everyone understands what you are doing.

A fairly generic approach (however, you need to specify label=...)
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\varitem}{}
 {
  \tl_set_eq:Nc \l_tmpa_tl { label\use:c{@enumctr} }
  \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \use:c{@enumctr} }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \{\u{l_tmpb_tl}\} } { \0 \$\'\$ } \l_tmpa_tl
  \item[\l_tmpa_tl]
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item BLA
  \item BLAA
  \varitem BLAAA
  \item BLAAAA
  \item BLAAAAA
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
  \item BLA
  \item BLAA
  \varitem BLAAA
  \item BLAAAA
  \item BLAAAAA
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
  \item BLA
  \item BLAA
  \varitem BLAAA
  \item BLAAAA
  \item BLAAAAA
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

We exploit the fact that enumitem redefines \label<ctr>, so we save the current meaning and modify it to add a prime after the counter representation, then use \item[...] that will not step the counter.


Thank you! That is so cool and advanced. Oh, is there any chance to reach your website? I tried but it gives an error...
